# DataTables: Store string representation of JSON object in column

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'm building a DataTables js table which has multiple child rows for some of the parent rows. I need to be able to search the child rows from the parent table. This data is being loaded from a JSON array with nested arrays in each of the parent objects.

I need to figure out how to convert the nested object to the string representation so I can load it into a hidden column to enable searching.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getHistoryJson")',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            ajaxData = $.parseJSON(data);
            table = $('#history').DataTable({
                data: ajaxData,
                dataSrc: '',
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        defaultContent: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>'
                    },
                    { data: "ID" },
                    { data: "Location" },
                    { data: "Address" },
                    { data: "Type" },
                    { data: ajaxData.nestedObject STRING HERE, visible: false}
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to stringify a nested object at that point. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please show a sample of your data representing a single record and explain what part of it you would like to include in a hidden column?

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData.nestedObject)`

Comment: I did try JSON.stringify, however datatables would throw a parameter not found error when building the table. However, I did come up with a maybe not so great workaround... Since I only needed to be able to search on specific values in each of the child rows, and not everything (IDs, data used for other methods, etc).. I just built a string object on the parent with all the "searchable" values for the children and assigned that to a hidden column.

Comment: { "data": function(data){return JSON.stringify(data.anyNestedObject);} } works for me.